# Gaming Website: Schema Design

Tags: schema

I want to make a gaming website for Magic the Gathering to report event results and management user decks.

Here's what I have so far.

Event is a tournament with Players competing in the tournament.
Players have Decks, which is a like deck of cards (in this case 60 Magic the Gathering cards).

So, the Decks table has these columns with foreign Ids related to the Events and Players table:

- event_id
- player_id

However, I also want the users to have Decks. Users are different from Players. Users log into the site. Then, they create and edit Decks.

Should I just create one Decks table or have a 2nd Decks table like UserDecks?

If I have one Decks table, it would have these columns:

- event_id
- player_id
- user_id

However, the event Decks would not have user_ids and the user Decks would not have event_ids or player_ids. Is it okay to have null in columns with foreign Ids?

I could just do a Decks table for event decks and a UserDecks table for user decks but it doesn't seem right to have two Decks table that are the same except for some different columns with foreign Ids?

Comment: Could you describe more what an "event" is and why it has "decks"? Could you be clearer about whether a "deck" is required to be owned by a player? It seems not, but you say "Decks belong to Players". Is there a difference between a "User" and a "Player"?

Comment: Event is a tournament with Players competing in the tournament. Players have Decks, which is a like deck of cards (in this case 60 Magic the Gathering cards). Users are different from Players. Users log into the site. Then, they create and edit Decks.

Comment: A Deck is required to be owned by a Player or a User.

Comment: I would suggest users and players are collapsed into one entity. They are both representations of people and will have the same attributes. Probably a good question - why do you separate them?

Comment: Would there be limits on a deck to be used in a tournament (i.e., a `player` deck) vs. a deck created by a user, not for use in a tournament (i.e., a `user` deck)? for example, a user deck could have 30 - 150 cards; a player deck must have exactly 60 cards. This would be the only reason to consider distinct tables; and, even here, I'd use a `ForTournament` Boolean to control the set of rules to apply to each deck, rather than creating two separate tables with the same exact columns.

Comment: Players are the people that did well in an Event so they don't log in. Users are people the sign up to the site and log in and create, edit, and deck their decks. Basically, one part of the site is Events and the people that did well in those events (aka Players), the other part of the site is people that join the site (Users) and create decks. Users also are able to edit their decks. But Users can't join Events because I'm only recording past Events that have already happened. But both types of people create the same Decks.

Comment: This question was closed prematurely IMO. "Too broad" is incorrect, this question was quite specific concerning the relationship and de-duplication between Users/Players. The answer given and accepted showed this. Please consider re-opening as it may help others grappling with the same design decision. @mustaccio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your basic design shouldn't be anymore complex than I have drawn in the picture below:

[image]

This assumes that you have only one entity representing a person ("Player", could be "User" though), that decks MUST belong to a person and that multiple people can enter an Event as Participants. I assume they bring their own decks with them and that Events cannot own Decks.

Comment: There might be a `Participant_Event_Deck` table, if you need to identify the particular `deck` a `player` used as a `participant` in a particular `event` - since each player can have multiple decks. If a participant can use multiple decks within a tournament, this would have to be its own table. If a participant can only use one deck in any given tournament, then the `deck_id` could be included in `participant`.

Comment: So, instead of creating Players, would I just create Users? That seems so weird because those Users would never log into the site. So, for those Players, do I just put null for the name and email fields?

Comment: How do you identify a player? If they don't have a name, what details would you record about them to identify them?

Comment: I would identify Player by their name. I think the critical thing I did not mention is that the Player information comes from an Event that already happened. The site does not run Events. Instead, it records the results of Events that already happened. I do this to gather data to analyze similar to a basketball stathead who records the stats of NBA players to do data analysis.

Comment: On the other hand, a User is someone who registers on the site because they want a tool to manage their decks. My analogy is content management systems, or CMS, for writers like WordPress, but in this case I would be creating a deck management system for Magic the Gathering fans (Users). A User is not related to Events because the site does not run Events.

Comment: Yep, so your assumption is correct - for Players you would only enter their names, for Users their details would be more complete. You could also have a "PersonType" field on the Person/Player/User table to indicate whether they are a User or a Player - U or P option. But I urge you to keep them in the same entity. A question you should ask is - what if a Player becomes a User? Someone who has previously played and you recorded the tournament, could want to become a registered user and associate their previous games - easy if they are findable in the Player table.

Comment: Good question and thanks for your answer. Not sure what I would do in that situation. I probably would keep them separate because decks of players and decks of users should be separated on the site since they have different use cases. The decks of players is just for show and data analysis while the decks of users is for managament. Many of the decks of users will be hidden because the users don't want them public (basically, to keep strategy hidden).

Comment: I would still recommending keeping the same entity for the same person. Allow the user to define which decks and events they have participated in are publicly viewable, with the default set to none. That way if your system ever evolves (and it definitely will if it catches on), you won't be stuck with a massive user de-duplication job, which is sometimes impossible to do well due to a lack of user information. It will probably be advantageous at some point for a player that has become a user to be able to view their historical tournaments to review their tactics, for instance.

Comment: Great points. Thanks. I learned a lot from your answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing example in your explanation.Your example is not so common.

For Example User log in and create 2 deck then it will look like

```
UserID  DeckID
1   1
1   2
```

Question 1 : Will Player use deck created by USER or they will create their own Deck ?What kind of relation is share between Player and User.

Question 2 : Like playing card is alwys same.Is there any limit for magic card or it can be anything under the sky.

```
PlayerID    DeckID  EventID
1   3   1
1   5   1
```

Both of them will be in seperate table.
Though explain with example and what query will arise.

I think query will get complicated if they are in same table.
Also just becasue only DeckID is share between User and Player do not mean they will in same place.